# Piecewise expanding map

Tags: ds.dynamical-systems

I think that piecewise expanding maps on the unit interval have been studied.  Is there something analogous in dimension 2 with the same good properties? In other words, maybe I want some good results which hold for piecewise expanding maps, and can be extended to higher dimension, such as the results about Perron-Frobenius operators.

Comment: Expansive maps on $d$-dimensional branched manifolds are considered often in the study of dynamics on 'tiling spaces' and Perron-Frobenius theory is used extensively there. Does that count?

Comment: Is there any reference?

Comment: The starting point is a paper by [Anderson and Putnam](https://www.cambridge.org/core/journals/ergodic-theory-and-dynamical-systems/article/topological-invariants-for-substitution-tilings-and-their-associated-castalgebras/5D7DB90543165287CA5C4CBF012323F5) but there's much more to be said after that, e.g. [Sadun's work](https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0210179.pdf).

Comment: Thank you . That seems to be an interesting topic

Answer (score 1):

If you are interested in local diffeomorphisms, where the map is continuous everywhere, then Chapters 11 and 12 of the book ["Foundations of Ergodic Theory" by Viana and Oliveira](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=3558990) has a very good account.

If you want to allow discontinuities, so that the map really is *piecewise* expanding, then in addition to the paper that Rafael linked to, there is a series of papers by Jerome Buzzi (and some co-authors) from 1997-2003 that would be worth looking at:

- ["Intrinsic ergodicity of affine maps in $[0,1]^d$", Monatsh. Math., 1997](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=1462857)
- ["Markov extensions for multi-dimensional dynamical systems", Israel J. Math, 1999](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=1714974)
- ["Absolutely continuous invariant measures for arbitrary expanding piecewise R-analytic mappings of the plan", ETDS, 2000](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=1764923)
- ["Conformal measures for multidimensional piecewise invertible maps", ETDS, 2001](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=1849600) (with Paccaut and Schmitt)
- ["Thermodynamical formalism for piecewise invertible maps: absolutely continuous invariant measures as equilibrium states, 2001](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=1858553)
- ["Uniqueness of equilibrium measures for countable Markov shifts and multidimensional piecewise expanding maps", ETDS, 2003](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=2018604) (with Sarig)

Comment: Thank you for the references.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this paper by [P. Eslami](https://peymaneslami.com/) will answer your question

https://arxiv.org/pdf/1711.09245.pdf. Check the references as well.

Comment: Thank you. I will read the article.